# My agent ES and DE languages are gone I need them back

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an agent which has 3 languages which are ENG, ES and DE. ENG is main language, I have created DE and ES version and implemented to ES and DE websites.
Now, I only see ENG language button under my agent name there are not DE and ES languages. But in ES and DE website, ES and DE agents are working.

How can I take back to my ES and DE agent on my dialogflow console? please help me
[you can see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tajWR.png)